# NTP: Understand Client's request

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ntp

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and try to build up my own NTP server (different hardware, own software) for this ubuntu client.

The client's request:
I got 48 bytes, which seems to fit to the specification with following content

```
#00: 00 00 00 23
#01: 00 00 00 00
...
#09: 00 00 00 00
#10: A0 71 DB DD
#11: A8 F8 5E 12
```

At the first byte, I expected a valid NTP protocol id (3?) and a valid mode (client), but I see only 0.
The on ubuntu has never been set. It's a hardware without RTC.

Why do I get requests like this?
Is there any possibility to configure the ntp protocol version?

Comment: When you say that you "try to build up my own NTP server", what do you mean by that? Put together the hardware and software needed, or that you want to write the NTP server software yourself? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I want to write my own simple NTP server on my own. (Hardware with RTC, providing a time information with low accuracy for my use case).
Till now, I only collected client's request and did nothing more than listening on the server's side.